# How can a model be asigned to a User automatically?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

So I am coding an e-commerce on Django in which in order to add items to cart, you need to be a customer. However, you log into the page as a user, which isnt the same. How can a customer be asigned to the User once it is created automatically? If it cannot be done automatically, then how can I insert a form to create the customer and for it to be related to the user?
I'll insert some screenshots of the customer model and the views which matter.

this is the Customer model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
device = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    if self.name:
        name = self.name
    else:
        name = self.device
    return str(name)
```

here

this is the add to cart function in views.py

```
def cart(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer = customer, complete = False)
    items = order.orderitem_set.all()
else:
    items = []
    order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}

context = {'items': items, 'order': order}
return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```

And this is how I managed to delete items from the cart or more specifically the OrderItem model:

```
def deleteitem(request, id):
if request.method == "POST":
     
    

    item = OrderItem.objects.get(product = id)
    item.delete()
    return render(request, "store/deletecartitem.html", {'item': item})

if  OrderItem.objects.all == 0:
    customer =   customer = request.user.customer
    order = Order.objects.get(customer = customer)
    order.delete()
```

I could manually relate a customer to a user which has been already created from the Djnago admin , but it just wouldn't be eficient. I'd like that when a user is registered, a customer is asigned to it automatically. Thank
you

Comment: why do you need `email` and `name` with your `Customer` model while they already exists with the related `User` by default?

Comment: Honestly I do not have a clue lol. Im a beginner. I could remove that then but I'd have to change my functions right?

Comment: I mean all I care about is being able to have a functional "add to cart" for customers who are logged in the page

Comment: Can you insert the source code as code sample instead of  images please. Makes it easier for people to help you. Thank you.

Comment: I just added the code. Huge thanks already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trivial question about Django `User` model extension. You can understand more if you searched about *Best practices to extend Django User model*.

But generally, there are two common approaches that most of developers do:

- Extending the `User` model by create a custom model like `Customer` that inherits from `AbstractUser`. This solution is the most flexible and easiest one, as you will have the same default Diango `User` model but with extra fields that you can add easily ongoing anytime through your development. If you like this approach and fits with your business case, you have to do it from the very beginning of development. Or, if you don't care about the old migrations, you can delete your database (if it is `sqlite`) and delete all your migrations files, and do a fresh `python manage.py makemigrations` after implementing the mentioned solution. Also, this is a better approach if you want to add something like `device` parameter that you want your user to add it directly while registration.

**`AbstractUser` approach:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Customer(AbstractUser):
    device = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

- The second approach is nearly what you did, but it needs more custom work (and surely depends on your business case). It is about having a new model like `Customer` that extends the `User` model by one-to-one relationship. Then, you can do the auto-creation and auto-save of the `Customer` model parallel with the `User` model using `signals` by doing the below

**Your approach:**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    device = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Customer.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_customer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.customer.save()
```

But in this case, the user will have to update his customer parameters later like `device` parameter.

Comment: Huge thanks!!!! I'll try both solutions and see which is best for my project. Once again thank you

Comment: You are welcome! If you see my answer as the right answer, please mark it as the accepted answer of your question. If it is also beneficial, please do vote up. Try always to show your appreciation to the people who helps you in any question ;)

Comment: so whenever I try to login my page I get an error message saying "User object has no attribute Customer". I tried with the second approach you gace me. How can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have updated it. It should be `instance.customer.save()` instead of `instance.Customer.save()`